# How do I set min and max resize sizes for my main window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a gui window which I can resize. I want to set min resizing values (and max as well) so that my widgets would not be swallowed when making the window too small or app would not look ugly when resized too much.

[image]

How do I set min and max resize sizes for my main window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `minsize` and `maxsize` functions:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=200, height=200)
root.maxsize(width=650, height=500)
root.mainloop()
```